# Center alignment in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a single page with a class (container) and two ids inside.

I want it to align the class container so that it always stays in the center of the page (horizontally and vertically). This container has to adapt to different screen sizes so specifying the exact number of pixels for container may not be an option.

Here is what my CSS looks like:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    margin-right: 4vw;
    margin-left: 4vw;
    display: block;
}

#titletext {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: justify;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: none;
}

#signtext {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

html file looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="titletext">some text here</div>
        <div id="signtext">some more text here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried several solutions for this problem that I found here and else where none of them worked for me.

Comment: see https://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/ on how to do this very easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure how things are nested with those two elements, but this should help

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}

#titletext {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: justify;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: none;

    /*center vertically & horizontally*/
    position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align:center;
}

#signtext {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="titletext">Centering
   <div id="signtext">Vertically & Horizontally</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked pretty well for my use, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need. I used a flexbox to center the container.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

#titletext {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: justify;
  font-size: 7.7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#signtext {
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="titletext">Title</div>
  <div id="signtext">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my snippet below I removed the `text-align-last: justify;` (makes a one-line text be justified), and added `text-align:center` and `margin: 0 auto` to `# signtext` to center both that DIV (with the auto margin) and its text contents:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    margin-right: 4vw;
    margin-left: 4vw;
    display: block;
}

#titletext {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: none;
}

#signtext {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="titletext">some text here</div>
        <div id="signtext">some more text here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way -

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    height:30%;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:35% 25% 35% 25%;
}

#titletext {
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: justify;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}

#signtext {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div id="titletext">some text here</div>
        <div id="signtext">some more text here</div>
    </div>
    </body>
```